# Monero CPU mining sofware for Solaris 11 OS

Tags: mining-software

I have some resources on machine running Solaris 11.3 OS on Intel CPU, but can not find any working software to mine Monero coins. Is there any chances to see it in a near future? Perhaps it is possible to adopt some Linux version? How hard is to change the code? Solaris OS is powerful to aggregate multiple CPUs - perhaps it is worth to try?

Answer (score 3):

The official [download](http://monero.org/downloads/) source is the best place to get Monero mining software. The Solaris operating system is not officially supported and is different from other OSes, though it shares some similarities with Linux.

In this [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/MoneroMining/comments/6wyq05/mine_with_sparcsolaris_hardware/) at Reddit the person asks about SPARC CPUs and Solaris, but seems to give up quickly trying.

- Q: Is there any chances to see it in a near future?

  Maybe.
- Q: Perhaps it is possible to adopt some Linux version?

  Perhaps.
- Q: How hard is to change the code?

  Changing the code is simple, getting it to work requires the ability to write software and compile it under the Solaris operating system.
- Q: Solaris OS is powerful to aggregate multiple CPUs - perhaps it is worth to try?

  Solaris aggregates more SPARC CPUs and the OS runs faster than using Intel x86 CPUs which are limited to 4 to 8 Platinum 8180's (which cost $80K).

  The IBM POWER9 has a bigger L1 Cache and is lower priced than Intel.

  "Q: Worth it to try?": Worth it to try something else first.

The other ways of doing it (Mining Monero) have many people working on it while those trying under Solaris are few or nearly none.

The operating system Solaris with Intel CPUs isn't much quicker nor does the speed of the operating system make much difference to mining speed. If you used SPARC CPUs you'd be a bit better off and a member of a tiny community.

Best to stick with Windows or Linux and be part of the largest communities.

How many years have you been programming under Solaris and working on improving Monero Software?

If you've been doing that a few years it shouldn't be too difficult. A couple of AMD 7601's under Linux is bound to be cheaper ($10K) and quick at 3100H/s 332w. Use of "free resources" is going to have some limits, especially if you're mining (otherwise the person with the free resources might as well use them themselves).

I don't think it's "worth it" but I can offer this deal: You do it and you can keep what you make.

Your answer is quite opinion based, but I know a fair bit about computers and have checked Monero mining benchmarks. If your time is free the community will appreciate the code you give back. Worth it to you, it's up to you. Not worth it to me.